# I'm trying to create a simple form using ExtJS and send the value into database

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

I am trying to create a simple form using `ExtJS` and send the value into database, but it doesn't insert what I enter value into my form. I don't know why it doesn't input the data into database.

---

PS: I am using Extjs 5

My `Extjs` form:

```
 Ext.define('Grid.view.main.Form', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        xtype:'form',
        title: 'User Form',
        id:'myformpanel',
        height: 120,
        width: '100%',
        autoScroll:true,
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            padding: 10
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        
        items: [{
            
                fieldLabel: 'TEST1',
                name: 'Test1'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST2',
                name: 'Test2'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST3',
                name: 'Test3'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST4',
                name: 'Test4'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST5',
                name: 'Test5'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST6',
                name: 'Test6'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST7',
                name: 'Test7'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST8',
                name: 'Test8'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST9',
                name: 'Test9'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST10',
                name: 'Test10'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST11',
                name: 'Test11'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'TEST12',
                name: 'Test12'
            },
            
        ],
    
       
    
         buttons: [{
            text: 'login',
            name:'submit',
        
        handler: function(){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'data/testform.php',
        method: 'POST',
        params: Ext.getCmp('myformpanel').getForm().getFieldValues(),
success: function(response){       
    Ext.Msg.alert('success ' + response.status);
},
failure: function(response){
    Ext.Msg.alert('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
}
});
                }
          });
        }
    }]
```

`testform.php`:

```
<?php

require_once('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $Test1=$_POST['Test1'];
        $Test2=$_POST['Test2'];
        $Test3=$_POST['Test3'];
        $Test4=$_POST['Test4'];
        $Test5=$_POST['Test5'];
        $Test6=$_POST['Test6'];
        $Test7=$_POST['Test7'];
        $Test8=$_POST['Test8'];
        $Test9=$_POST['Test9'];
        $Test10=$_POST['Tes10t'];
        $Test11=$_POST['Test11'];
        $Test12=$_POST['Test12'];

        $query="INSERT INTO testexcel (Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,Test6,Test7,Test8,Test9,Test10,Test11,Test12) VALUES ('$Test1','$Test2','$Test3','$Test4','$Test5','$Test6','$Test7','$Test8','$Test9','$Test10','$Test11','$Test12')";
}

?>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Do the values get sent to the server correctly?

Comment: in my firebug no error..."POST http://localhost/grid/grid/data/testform.php 
200 OK 3ms".. but nothing view in POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sir @Hown_  for helping me... i figure out what is the problem why isnt insert my data into database... because of my database is wrong configuration so this my code

//my extjs form panel

```
Ext.define('Grid.view.main.Form', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype:'form',



    title: 'User Form',
    id:'myformpanel',
    height: 120,
    width: '100%',
    autoScroll:true,
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        padding: 10
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },

    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'TEST1',
            name: 'Test1'


        },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST2',
            name: 'Test2'
                    },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST3',
            name: 'Test3'
                   },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST4',
            name: 'Test4'
                    },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST5',
            name: 'Test5'
                    },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST6',
            name: 'Test6'
                    },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST7',
            name: 'Test7'
                    },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST8',
            name: 'Test8'
                    },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST9',
            name: 'Test9'
                    },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST10',
            name: 'Test10'

        },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST11',
            name: 'Test11'

        },{
            fieldLabel: 'TEST12',
            name: 'Test12'

        },

    ],

    buttons: [{


        text: 'login',
        name:'submit',

    handler: function()
    {



        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'data/testform.php',
            method: 'POST',
            params: Ext.getCmp('myformpanel').getForm().getFieldValues(),
                success: function(response){       
                 Ext.Msg.alert('success ' + response.status);
    },
                failure: function(response){
                Ext.Msg.alert('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
    });




    }]



});
```

//my testform.php

```
<?php

require_once('database_connection.php');




    $Test1= isset($_POST['Test1']) ? $_POST['Test1'] : NULL;
    $Test2= isset($_POST['Test2']) ? $_POST['Test2'] : NULL;
    $Test3= isset($_POST['Test3']) ? $_POST['Test3'] : NULL;
    $Test4= isset($_POST['Test4']) ? $_POST['Test4'] : NULL;
    $Test5= isset($_POST['Test5']) ? $_POST['Test5'] : NULL;
    $Test6= isset($_POST['Test6']) ? $_POST['Test6'] : NULL;
    $Test7= isset($_POST['Test7']) ? $_POST['Test7'] : NULL;
    $Test8= isset($_POST['Test8']) ? $_POST['Test8'] : NULL;
    $Test9= isset($_POST['Test9']) ? $_POST['Test9'] : NULL;
    $Test10= isset($_POST['Test10']) ? $_POST['Test10'] : NULL;
    $Test11= isset($_POST['Test11']) ? $_POST['Test11'] : NULL;
    $Test12= isset($_POST['Test12']) ? $_POST['Test12'] : NULL;


        $query="INSERT INTO testexcel (Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,Test6,Test7,Test8,Test9,Test10,Test11,Test12) VALUES ('$Test1','$Test2','$Test3','$Test4','$Test5','$Test6','$Test7','$Test8','$Test9','$Test10','$Test11','$Test12')";
        mysql_query($query,$con);



?>
```

Hope this code will help the beginner like me....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess your request body is empty isnt it? Try to insert the form data into the `params:` config of your Ajax request. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'data/testform.php',
    method: 'POST',
    params: this.ownerCt.ownerCt.getForm().getFieldValues(),
    success: function(response){       
        Ext.Msg.alert('success ' + response.status);
    },
    failure: function(response){
        Ext.Msg.alert('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

`this.ownerCt.ownerCt.getForm()` is not the nicest way to get to your Form - though i couldnt find an other way to access it in your example. you could give your form an `id` and work with `Ext.getCmp(id)` if you like that more. This would look like this `params: Ext.getCmp('myformpanel123').getForm().getFieldValues()`.

Comment: i do what did you say... see the codes above i edit it.. still no insert value into database

Comment: do you have the data in your request body? and btw could you check what isset($_POST['submit']) returns? place some echos in your php code an check the response of your php request. i'd guess isset($_POST['submit']) returns false and so your php script doesnt enter the if statement. Try if(isset($_POST['Test1']))... or add an submit property to your params json.

Comment: did you check the other things i suggested too?

Comment: yes.. i erase isset($_POST['submit']){} then i change all my $_POST to  ..$Test1= isset($_POST['Test1']) ? $_POST['Test1'] : NULL; and so on.. and add an echo $Test1 but and check it to the php file but noting to output and still not insert the value of form into database... thanks for helping me... can you help again please Thanks